# Regex pattern for ^A

Tags: java, regex

I need to remove `^A` from an incoming  string, I'm looking for a regex pattern for it

Don’t want to use `\\p{cntrl}` , I don’t want to delete the other control characters coming in  the string

Comment: You can escape special characters for an exact match of that character. You can use sites such as [this one](https://regex101.com) to test your regexes easily.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have tried all possible combinations it’s not working

Comment: Any reason why you need to use regex to remove a fixed substring? Basic string manipulation would be more efficient and require no regex knowledge.

Comment: It’s a  parameterized that’s to be removed

Comment: As long as the parameter itself isn't a regex it doesn't matter. I'll post a regex-less answer for illustration

Answer (score 1):

You should use escaping for '^A':

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String value = "remove special char ^A A and B";
    System.out.println(value.replaceAll("\\^A", ""));
}
```

Output:

> remove special char  A and B

Comment: Try using this string  “remove special char ^A A and B”

Comment: If I use \\^A it removes my stand alone “A” as well output is like “remove special char   and B”

Comment: @megharaina: You're using forward slashes there.

Comment: Wrote it mistakenly , using the correct escape only

Comment: Can u pls try it with the string that gave ?

Comment: @megharaina: I have tried and it works on my test. I have just updated the answer. Have a look, please.

Comment: Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you avoid using regex and instead use basic string manipulation :

```
String toRemove = "^A";
yourString.replace(toRemove, "");
```

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/xHZ8nz).

Be careful not to use `String` methods that work on regexs, especially since the name of the methods aren't very informative ([`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) replaces all occurences of a fixed string, [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) replaces all occurences that match a regex pattern).